# Rails 4 execute associated model method from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let say we have a code:

Model:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.make_noise
    puts 'bow-wow'
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class DogsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Dog.make_noise
  end
end
```

This will work, but I would rather like to write the controller `index` method code like: `AssociatedModel.make_noise` or `Model.make_noise`

Is it possible in Rails to call associated model method without using its class name in code?

This would be useful if I would like to use inheritance and make let say PetsController which will be the base for all pets (or a PetNoise Concern included for every applicable controller) and declare there index method.

I'm not sure if I explained this well enough.

OK. The one way (which i don't like) is to write `PetsController` method like this:

```
def index
  params[:controller].classify.constantize.make_noise
end
```

This way if I inherit `PetsController` from `DogsController` it will still work without defining separate index inside `DogsController`. But maybe there are other more neat solutions.

Comment: So... you want to call a method on an object... without knowing what the object is? Sorry, I don't get it, you'll have to explain more. I mean, you can assign the model to a variable (object pointer, essentially) and call a method on that. Is that what you want? Someone somewhere has to know what `self.model` is.

Comment: Sorry the example was wrong I didn't of course mean the instance method but the class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I also explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846350/rails-4-using-controller-concern-to-dry-update-methods/28846736#28846736), you can determine the model using `params[:controller]`. Like this:

```
params[:controller] # => "dogs"
params[:controller].classify # => "Dog"
```

Therefore you can write your index action "generically" like this:

```
def index
  model_class = params[:controller].classify.constantize
  model_class.make_noise
end
```

Comment: Yeah that's it but is there any better solution to this (I really don't like `params[:controller]` part) or is it the only solution? Does `params[:controller]` will always be correct for associated model name?

Comment: @user2041318 not sure what you mean by "better" solution. You could do it based on the class name, which is even messier IMO. E.g. the inherited_resources gem uses `self.class.name.sub(/Controller$/, '').singularize`.

Comment: I was just hoping for some short alternative like `self.modelname` but maybe there is no such thing. Anyway thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: As explained here http://blog.littleimpact.de/index.php/2008/08/13/constantize-with-care/ constantize could be dangerous but it seems to be ok for `params[:controller]`